# Removing framework public headers in runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I am using a framework for developing a Cocoa application. The framework exposes its public headers in Versions/A/Headers path as expected.

Is there any way by which I can hide/delete this headers once I have the compiled application build in place? Will that affect any features or method calls at runtime of my app?

Comment: Headers exist to give the compiler something substantive to work off of.  Symbols are what really matters to the linker and at runtime.  Just mark all your headers "private" or "project", alter your header search paths, and keep plugging away like normal.  The only thing you have to expose is the minimum required for the consumers of your framework to, you know, actually use your framework.

Comment: After i build the app, I see the Headers of the used frameworks in the following location:

Comment: After i build the app, I see the Headers of the used frameworks in the following location: **`MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/3rdParty.framework/Versions/A/`**. How can I remove this from MyApp before shipping? Also, any idea why Cocoa.framework headers are not seen under the contents of MyApp?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: For security reasons. I am not allowed to port my app with Headers files exposed holding private informations like developer names, etc.

Comment: So put those into a project header and only import it into implementation files and equally private headers.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove framework headers at build time with a 'Run Script' build phase.  You need to create a new 'Run Script Build Phase' after 'Copy Frameworks' build phase.  And this new phase should execute something like

```
FRAMEWORKS_DIR="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.${WRAPPER_EXTENSION}/Contents/Frameworks"
FRAMEWORK_NAME="3rdParty.framework"

if [ -d "${FRAMEWORKS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}/Versions/A/Headers" ]; then
  rm    "${FRAMEWORKS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}/Versions/A/Headers/"*".h"
  rm -r "${FRAMEWORKS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}/Versions/A/Headers"
  rm    "${FRAMEWORKS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}/Headers"
fi
```

In the end, app target build phases should look like

[image]

Screenshot also contains irrelevant to the question commands:

- `set -euo pipefail` so that entire script fails when some of its commands fails;
- `set -x` so that executed commands are printed to build log.

Comment: Yeah this works. I just had to add to an extra -rm for removing .pch :)